Sunflower Plot Using ggplot2
I posted the following question on Posit Community three months ago but have not received an answer. I am reposting it here in the hope that someone can help me.
I am interested in creating a sunflower plot using ggplot2. In a sunflower plot, overplotted points are visualized as "sunflowers," with each "leaf" representing the number of data points at that location. While I am familiar with the sunflowerplot() function in the graphics package, I am exploring ggplot2 for its seamless integration with other geom layers. Here is a base graphics example:
tb <- tibble::tibble(
  x = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 1), rep(0, 3), rep(1, 2)),
  y = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 1), rep(1, 3), rep(0, 2))
)
sunflowerplot(tb$x, tb$y)

I am specifically seeking a ggplot2 solution that mirrors the functionality of geom_count(), but uses the number of "petals" rather than point size to represent counts. While I am aware of alternatives like geom_jitter() or geom_beeswarm() for mitigating overplotting, my focus remains on crafting a sunflower plot.
Despite scouring the web, I have yet to discover a suitable ggplot2 add-on package or workaround. The term "sunflower plot" surfaced in a thread titled Plotting a Scatter Plot with Categorical Data within the Posit community. However, this discussion lacked accompanying code, and the featured plot was not a sunflower plot.
If anyone has encountered a ggplot2-based sunflower plot solution or has a clever hack to achieve this visualization, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Start with looking at the source code of graphics:::sunflowerplot.default. If you are familiar with how to define a geom for ggplot2 (I'm not), it shouldn't be too difficult to implement.

I thought this would be very tricky, but thanks to this great answer on custom shapes in ggplot2 I've been able to do it.
The library of default shapes used by R isn't expansive enough to do this, so you need to use grid to create your own custom shapes by drawing lines between coordinates of your choosing. ggpmisc will let you add these' grobs to a ggplot sing 'geom_grob'. Here's the code:
library(ggpmisc)
library(grid)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(pi)

## Function to make shape based on count
make_shape <- function(n){
  
  # We need our new shapes to have the same aspect ratio as the whole plot
  dev_size <- dev.size()
  dev_ratio <- dev_size[2]/dev_size[1]
  
  # If n == 1, make a point
  if(n == 1) grob <- pointsGrob(0.5, 0.5, pch = 16)
  else {
    
    ## If n > 1, define the extremeties of the 'star'
    ## (A sequence of length n that starts at 1 nth of the circle and ends at a whole circle)
    extremities <- 2 * pi * seq(1/n, 1, length.out = n)
    
    ## Create x and y vectors for the points of the shape
    x <- y <- numeric(2 * n - 1)
    
    ## Odd elemetns of x are the sin() of the angles of the extremities
    ## Use dev_ratio to get the lengths of each petal consistent
    x[seq_along(x) %% 2 == 1] <- unit(0.5 + 0.15 * dev_ratio * sin(extremities), "npc")
    ## At even elemnts of x, we go back to the centre, creating a star shape
    x[seq_along(x) %% 2 == 0] <- 0.5
    
    ## Odd elements of y are the cos() of the angles
    y[seq_along(y) %% 2 == 1] <- unit(0.5 + 0.15 * cos(extremities), "npc")
    y[seq_along(y) %% 2 == 0] <- 0.5
    
    ## Create a grob
    grob <- linesGrob(x, y , gp = gpar(lwd = 2))
  }
  grob
}

test <- tibble(
  x = 1:10,
  count = 1:10
) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(shape = list(make_shape(count)))

ggplot(test) + 
  geom_grob(aes(x, y = "Shapes",  label = shape)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10) + 
  
  labs(y = NULL, x = "N", title = "Sunflower plot example") + 
  theme_minimal()+ 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())


Created on 2024-05-29 with reprex v2.1.0

Inspired by Captain Hat's comment below,  for independence from aspect ratio you could do this:
sunflower_plot <- function(
  d, 
  petal_len = 0.05, 
  petal_col = "red", 
  dot_col = "black") 
{
  dev_size <- dev.size()
  dev_ratio <- dev_size[2]/dev_size[1]

  tmp <- d %>% 
    # Prepare 
    group_by(x, y) %>% 
    # How many petals are needed at this point?   
    summarise (N = n(), .groups = "keep") %>% 
    # Define the petals
    group_map(
      function(.x, .y) {
        .x  %>% 
          expand(nesting(x, y, N), n = (1:N)) %>% 
          mutate(
            Theta = 2 * n * pi / N,
            x1 = ifelse(N == 1, x, x + petal_len * sin(Theta) * dev_ratio),
            y1 = ifelse(N == 1, y, y + petal_len * cos(Theta))
          )
      },
      .keep = TRUE
    ) %>% 
    bind_rows() 
  tmp %>%
    ggplot() +
      # Draw the petals for non-singleton points
      geom_segment(
       aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x1, yend = y1), 
       colour = petal_col
      ) +
      # Draw singleton points
      geom_point(
        data = tmp %>% filter(N == 1), 
        aes(x = x, y = y), 
        colour = dot_col
      )
}

tb %>% sunflower_plot()

which gives

and

for a sample aspect ratio other than 1.  Constant petal lengths will not be preserved if the aspect ratio is altered after the plot is created.  (For example, when resizing the RStudio viewer pane.)
Alternatively, you could use coord_fixed to fix the aspect ratio of the plot even if the plot is resized after it is created.  However, this may mean that not all the window is used to display the plot
sunflower_plot1 <- function(
  d, 
  petal_len = 0.05, 
  petal_col = "red", 
  dot_col = "black", 
  ratio = 1
) {
  tmp <- d %>% 
    group_by(x, y) %>% 
    summarise (N = n(), .groups = "keep") %>% 
    group_map(
      function(.x, .y) {
        .x  %>% 
          expand(nesting(x, y, N), n = (1:N)) %>% 
          mutate(
            Theta = 2 * n * pi / N,
            x1 = ifelse(N == 1, x, x + petal_len * sin(Theta) * ratio),
            y1 = ifelse(N == 1, y, y + petal_len * cos(Theta))
          )
      },
      .keep = TRUE
    ) %>% 
    bind_rows() 
  tmp %>%
    ggplot() +
      geom_segment(
        aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x1, yend = y1), 
        colour = petal_col
      ) +
      geom_point(
        data = tmp %>% filter(N == 1), 
        aes(x = x, y = y), 
        colour = dot_col
      ) +
      coord_fixed(ratio)
}

tb %>% sunflower_plot(ratio = 0.25)


For a plot which both responds to changes in aspect ratio and fills the viewer pane, I think you will need to define a new geom.

I have just tried out your solution. The aspect ratio of the symbols depends on the aspect ratio of the plot. Is there a way to ensure that all petals of the sunflowers are equally long, independent of the plot's aspect ratio, as for the base-R sunflowerplot() function?

@MichaelGastner You can use the values of dev.size() to get a ratio of device height:width, and then multiply you x values by this ratio to get consistent petal lengths - see my answer for an implementation of this.

A late option to consider (using the mtcars dataset as an example).
The sunflower is limited to 8 petals (the number of petals would likely become more difficult to easily discern in greater number), so would require binning for counts above 8.
library(ggfoundry)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)

# geom_count
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, carb)) +
  geom_count() +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(n)), stat = "sum", colour = "white") +
  ggtitle("geom_count") +
  theme_bw()

# sunflower
shapes <- shapes_cast() |>
  filter(set == "flower") |>
  pull(shape)

p2 <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, carb)) +
  geom_casting(aes(shape = factor(after_stat(n)), group = after_stat(n)), 
               size = 0.25, stat = "sum", colour = "#582d03", fill = "#ffdb3b") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes) +
  labs(title = "Sunflower with ggfoundry", shape = "Petals") +
  theme_bw()

# Plot side-by-side
p1 + p2 + plot_layout(guides = "collect", axes = "collect")


Created on 2024-05-31 with reprex v2.1.0
